# Is adding .json to the end of a URL required for a default Rails resource to respond as a JSON request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a vanilla Rails 4.2 app for a demo of building a JSON API with Rails.

```
bundle exec rails g scaffold widget name
```

Out of the box, Rails provides an easy way to fetch a resource as JSON by simply adding `.json` to the end of the URL.

```
/widgets.json
# or...
/widgets/123.json
```

However, I was wondering what is the most simple way to allow Rails to respond as JSON by using other means than simply appending `.json`. Do I need to send an Accept header in the request? Or do I have to explicitly `respond_to :json` in order to add this support? I also need to continue to support HTML, but wanted a clean URL. What do I need to do?

Comment: You can use default `format` in your route declaration as `json` also.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Good tip. In this case, I don't want to set JSON as the default. I just want to find the cleanest, most REST-friendly way to perform a JSON request without adding .json to the URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Rails to respond with json based on headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241126/how-to-get-rails-to-respond-with-json-based-on-headers)

Answer (score 1):

For defining all the routes to json use the following code.

```
resources :you_resouce, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

For specific route use the following code.

```
scope :format => true, :constraints => { :format => 'json' } do
  get '/endpoint' => "controller#action_method"
end
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer the question. I am asking what can be done on the client to request a JSON response.