# How to get Rails to respond with json based on headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an API with Rails 4 and in my controller I'm using `respond_to` to differentiate between `html` and `json` request which all works fine. While testing my API in Postman, I've added the following header: `Content-Type: application/json` but in my request I still need to add `.json` at the end of it like so: `https://myapi.com/api/users.json` otherwise Rails will respond with `html` even though the aforementioned header is present.

My question is this: is there a way that Rails can recognise the `Content-Type: application/json` header and respond with `json` without me using the `.json` part in the url like so: `https://mypai.com/api/users`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to set the `Accept` header to `Accept: application/json`

If you're curious as to why, and the difference between the two headers, the answers to this post explain it best: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers

Comment: Where should I set the `Accept` header then?

Comment: Actually, never mind! I got it. Just for reference (you might wan to edit your answer for reference) you need to add another header `Accept: application/json`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any link helper inside a view, simple add the format information, like `posts_path(format: :json)`.

Comment: I'm not using views though