# Rails HAML View Rendering Raw HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, haml

I'm trying to render a simple view using HAML that shows a collection of JSON objects with a header above. The route I'm using is `get 'posts.json', to: 'posts#posts_as_json'`. This renders the below view.

#### posts_as_json.haml

```
%h1 Posts As JSON
%div.gutter-spacing
  =raw(@posts)
```

The problem I'm running into is that the page will render raw HTML tags as well as the JSON itself. I've been trying to figure out what the issue is and based on some experimentation I think it's directly tied to using `.json` in my routing. If I remove that it seems to render the HTML as expected. Update: This is definitely the root of the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194434/is-adding-json-to-the-end-of-a-url-required-for-a-default-rails-resource-to-res)

Using the route `'posts.json'` is a requirement of my project, but I need to be able to search the parsed JSON as well which I have previously solved with a simple HTML text input tied to a javascript function. How can I use this endpoint while still rendering HTML alongside the JSON data?

Comment: If possible you should use another route like `posts_as_json`, but if you really have no way around the requirement, you can do it with the anser below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if you request a `.json` format, rails will automatically try to send it as a response with the corresponding MIME type `application/json`.

Now the browser gets a response that he thinks should be a JSON so it renders it as text.

You can override the MIME type for your render method:

```
render content_type: content_type: "text/html"
```

Or if you want to serve both request from the same controller action, you can do it with the `respond_to`-method:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render }
    format.json { render 'index_as_json.html', content_type: "text/html" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. For the time being I'm just going to pass a query param for filtering since that feels much more natural. If there are complaints I'll reiterate with this and see what happens.